# CI Datamapper: Iterate parent child

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I have categories and posts.
I would like to list all categories (parent), and all related posts (child). Without nested sets, complex queries. Relations setted up.

As i rembember from the documentation:

```
$categories = new Category();

foreach( $categories->get() as $category )
{
   echo $category->name;

   foreach( $category->post->get() as $post)
   {
       echo $post->title;
   }

}
```

Now if i have thousand categories, it will make a query for each category.

**What is the best practice in this case?**

1. Create two query for posts and categories and merge them into a tree with php?
2. Join two tables, one query and create the tree with php?
3. Somebody's smart idea :)

Answer (score 1):

I would create a dedicated model method that retrieves the data you want, and I'd retrieve it in batches (for pagination). Before I jump into the idea with some *example code*, the core concept is that you have two tables which you link via an **INNER JOIN** statement and that you limit your selects in batches. You then display data as you would normally in your view.

Let's say that you have a **category** table that looks something like this:

- id
- name

Let's also say that you have a **post** table that looks something like this:

- id
- name
- category_id

I would now basically retrieve the entries that you need, but also limit my results.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('category');
$this->db->join('post', 'post.category_id = category.id', 'inner');
$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Pagination saves you when you have to display a lot of data. If you however, **must display all the data at once**, consider using *Memcached*, *Gearman* or similar caching technology, so that you have better performance.